# Android replace text in pdf

Tags: android, kotlin, itext

I tried to replace text in my pdf with IText library, but then I get Contents and get string from bytes. I get 
0.0800 7996 instead of letters/
But val text right string.

```
fun manipulatePdf(src: String, dest: String) {
    val reader = PdfReader(src);
    val dict = reader.getPageN(1);
    val obj = dict.getDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);
    val text = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1);

    if (obj is PRStream) {
        val data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(obj);
        val string = String(data)
        string.replace("number", "1")
        obj.setData(string.toByteArray());
    }

    val stamper = PdfStamper(reader, FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: That code works only for very primitively built pdfs if at all. At the same time, though, it is dangerous and can damage the stream.

Comment: @mkl What other ways are there to change the text in pdf?

Comment: Usually text content in a PDF should be considered final. Adding some stuff is simple but removing specific parts is difficult. A dirty way would be to paint a white rectangle over the existing term and drawn the new one over it. A better way would involve the use of redaction methods which actually remove the pre-existing glyphs.